# How to integrate Jmeter Selenium webdriver to Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, jmeter

I have a java code for Selenium Jmeter tests. Now how can i integrate it with Jenkins? As i have two files .jmx and .jtl files also how to integrate Jmeter Graphs results with Jenkins
Below is my code

```
import org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine;
import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector;
import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.Summariser;
import org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService;
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.File;

public class RunJMeterTest {

    @Test
    public void executeJMeterTest() throws Exception {
        StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();

        JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("/path/to/your/jmeter/bin/jmeter.properties");
        JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome("/path/to/your/jmeter");
        JMeterUtils.initLocale();

        SaveService.loadProperties();

        HashTree testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(new File("/path/to/your/jmeter/extras/Test.jmx"));
        Summariser summer = null;
        String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", "summary");
        if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
            summer = new Summariser(summariserName);
        }
        String logFile = "/path/to/test/result.jtl";
        ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summer);
        logger.setFilename(logFile);
        testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], logger);

        jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
        jmeter.run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given you are able successfully run your test in Jenkins and getting .jtl file somewhere in the [Jenkins workspace](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project) you can "feed" the .jtl results file to [Jenkins Performance Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Performance+Plugin) which automatically analyses .jtl files, publishes performance trend charts, etc.

[image: JMeter Performance Plugin Results]

1. Install Jenkins Performance Plugin
2. Restart Jenkins to pick it up
3. Add a Post-Build step to publish performance test result report:

   [image: JMeter Post Build Step]
4. Specify results file location and pass/fail criteria:

   [image: JMeter Perfomrance Plugin Configuration]

More information:

- [How to Run Test with Performance Plugin](http://jenkinsci.github.io/performance-plugin/RunTests.html)
- [How to Build Reports with Peformance Plugin](http://jenkinsci.github.io/performance-plugin/Reporting.html)
- [How to Use the Jenkins Performance Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-jenkins-performance-plugin)

Comment: But Dmitri T how does the flow works? first we create a plan then we add the samplers and listeners and a .jtl file gets created where all the logs and results are saved and the test case is stored in .jmx file, and then jmeter.run() starts running in the test itself. When we inject the jmeter -n -s .jmx -l .jtl command is injected to jenkins does it again run the test?

Comment: Looking into your code, especially at this line: `String logFile = "/path/to/test/result.jtl";` it should produce .jtl file already, all you need to do is to configure the performance plugin to read this file

Comment: In that case you mean to say i do not need to create .jmx file in the code ? for Ex : // 
save generated test plan to JMeter's .jmx file format
                SaveService.saveTree(testPlanTree, new FileOutputStream("report\\jmeter_api_sample.jmx"));

Comment: What would be the command that i should inject to Jenkins job then? Because if i run jmeter -n .jmx -l .jtl then same test runs twice? how it works ?